# Is there a faster way to find distances on a sphere than Haversine?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

My task is to find the distance between the arbitrary point and many others on the sphere. Unfortunately, Haversine, even in vectorized form, does not satisfy in terms of speed, and I would like to find an option that will be faster for realtime calculation of the large data-set. I noticed that for a point lying on the pole, the distances to all others will be equal to their latitude. Maybe there are methods to transform the view of the coordinate system to center the point on the pole? Also I can adapt dataset before starting calculations, maybe I can somehow use the matrix of the precalculated distances to find distances to a new point? I will appreciate any ideas!

Comment: By distance do you mean across the surface or through the sphere? E.g; Would the distance between the north and south pole be the diameter or half the circumference? If across the surface, the distance would be $r\sqrt{(\Delta \phi)^2+(\Delta \theta)^2}$ where $\Delta \phi$ and $\Delta \theta$ are the differences in the longitude and latitude of the two points (measured in radians), and $r$ is the sphere's radius.

Comment: @Graviton Are you defining longitude and latitude using the usual mercator projection?  If so, the distances you've defined would be the distance on the mercator projection map, with the same distortion away from the equator, becoming extreme near the poles.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Excellent point; this is what happens when I attempt math after an 8 hour shift. Please disregard my earlier comment, unless for some strange reason you need distances on the Mercator projection.